# Number partition - prove recursive formula

Tags: combinatorics

Prove the following recursive formula:

$$ p_{k} (n) = p_{k-1} (n-1) + p_{k} (n-k)$$

Would you give me any hints how to start with this?

Edit: I'm sorry:

$p_{k} (n)$ - it is a number of partitions $n$ into $k$ parts.

Example

$p_{2} (4) = 2$  because $4= 3+1$ and $4=2+2$

Comment: What does $p_k(n)$ mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT: $p_k(n)$ is the number of partitions of $n$ into $k$ parts. There are two kinds of partitions of $n$ into $k$ parts: those having at least one part of size $1$, and those in which every part has size at least $2$. If every part has size at least $2$, you can subtract one from each part to get a partition of $n-k$ into $k$ parts. And if there’s a part of size $1$, you can ... ?

Comment: simply subtract a part of size 1 (because we are sure that there is at least one part of that size) and think what is the number of partitions of $n-1$ into $k-1$ parts. Magic. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Joseph: You’ve got it. You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** A partition of $n$ into $k$ parts can either have a $1$, or have no $1$'s.