# Derive a formula for this problem What are the possible no. of cases to express 100 in sum of other positive no.s

Tags: problem-solving, integer-partitions

Derive a formula for this problem:

> What are the possible number of cases to express $100$ as a sum of other positive numbers?

For example, $4$ can be expressed as a sum in the ways:

- $1+1+1+1$
- $2+1+1$
- $2+2$
- $3+1$ and lastly
- $4$ itself

so there are $5$ cases.

Comment: Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) out.

Comment: But can u give me a formula for it

Comment: Euler's recurrence formula, described in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1192906/recurrence-relation-recursive-formula-closed-formula-for-partition-numbers/1718559#1718559), is a reasonably efficient way of computing the partition numbers.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for finding integer partitions. [Check this out.](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Partition_(number_theory)&oldid=682278876#Approximation_formulas)

There is an exact formula available as an infinite series, given in the above reference.  Evaluating it, however, is highly complicated.  A good approximation for integer partitions of a number $n$ is 
$\dfrac{1}{4n\sqrt{3}}e^\left(\pi \sqrt{\dfrac{2n}{3}}\right)$