# How many unique ways are there to cut a rod?

Tags: combinatorics

This is related to the rod-cutting problem and counting the number of ways that you can cut it. I am interested in **counting** the total number of **unique** ways that you can cut the rod.

By unique or distinct, I mean that when you cut a rod, the order of the partitions shouldn't matter e.g.
cutting a rod of length 4 and be cut as $1+3$ or $3+1$. These should be considered the same.

I know that the brute force solution is $$2^{n-1}$$ but that has a lot of redundant states. Consider the rod of length 3, $2^{n-1}$ configurations are:

```
1 + 1 + 1
1 + 2
2 + 1          <- redundant
3
```

So it seems like the actual number of ways to cut a rod is less than $2^{n-1}$. What is the actual number and how would you go about calculating it?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are asking how many partitions are there of an integer.  You might want to start with something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)

Comment: How is the "number of unique ways you can cut the rod" defined?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is the sequence [A00041](https://oeis.org/A000041) in OEIS: the number of [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of integers. If you don't like wiki, try [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Partition.html).

There's no general formula available (as things often don't), but we have the [recurrence relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1344553/356647) and the generating function (see e.g. the wiki entry).

Just FYI, the ordered situation is the [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of integers.

Answer (score 1):

A rod of length $n$ can be cut at any of the positions $1$ inch, $2$ inches, up to $n-1$ inches. Therefore for each way of cutting the rod, there is a corresponding sequence of $0$s and $1$s of length $n-1$, with a $1$ in the $i$th place meaning that the rod is cut at this position and a $0$ meaning that it is not cut.

Since there are $2^{n-1}$ such sequences, there must be $2^{n-1}$ ways of cutting the rod.